# Meaning of the bolded texts

Tags: meaning, syntax

The vision is in effect a statement of strategic intent that serves to focus the energies of the organisation management towards the setting and achievement of specific goals and objectives. Its aspirational nature means that it is consistently revised, as each set of goals are achieved, and **further stretching future situations are established.**

What is the meaning of further stretching future situations?
I think it means the conditions that will lead one to future is established, but i have a doubt if it is correct.

Comment: It's a bit clumsily phrased, but the intended sense is *...and [as] situations arise in the future which further stretch [the ability of management to operate successfully]* - where ***arise*** is far more natural than ***be established***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paragraph appears to be about the use of a "vision statement" to guide the setting of goals for an organisation.

"Situations" are the conditions that the organisation may be in, or positions the organisation will take in the "future".  "Stretching" is a buzzword meaning "difficult but achievable", and the idea is that the organisation will "establish" situations (that is either choose a position, or analyse the conditions)  for itself in the future, and by considering the situation it is in, it will revise its vision and goals.

The is, of course, typical of management-speak, a type of jargon used by managers in businesses and like other technical terminology, it doesn't make much sense to people outside the group.

> (the vision) is consistently revised:
>
> - as each set of goals are achieved, and
> - as we learn about new future situations that will be challenging.

Comment: Syntactically, i think we can conclude different meaning, what's your opinion of it?

Comment: It is paired with "each set of goals is achieved".  So your interpretation must be consistent with "{the vision} is consistently revised as further stretching future situations are established."  I don't believe your interpretation can this simplified sentence.

Comment: Can i say **further stretching** modifies future situations?

Comment: & can you paraphrase it?

Comment: I read it as stretching modifies "future situations"   But to be honest - it is all just management buzz-speak.

Comment: I've added a paraphrase.